# Возможен ли вызов исключения?

Tags: исключения, c++

Предположим, где-нибудь, в каком-нибудь месте программы (не в начале), у нас есть следующий код:

```
int a = <некое значение>;
```

Но до этого места, скажем, в нашей программе уже было несколько сот других переменных и программа много раз обращалась к динамической памяти.
Возможна ли такая ситуация, что в системе закончится память, и вышеприведенный код приведен к выработке необрабатываемого исключения и аварийному завершению программы?
Либо же до этого new[] уже успеет вызвать std::bad_alloc и такая ситуация в принципе невозможна?
Другими словами, есть ли гарантия отсутствия исключений в данном случае?

Собственно говоря, инструкция int a = some_val просто транслируется в ассемблерную команду наподобии mov eax, ds[index]; т.е. по идее исключение быть и не должно, вопрос только в том, резервируется ли сегмент данных полностью до начала работы программы для всех переменных либо же приобретение ресурсов происходит динамически, в ходе работы программы, как в случае с динамической памятью.

Получается, чем больше у нас имен переменных, тем больше индексов в программе, по которым происходит обращение, и тем больше должен быть объем резервируемого сегмента данных.

Правда все равно остается вопрос, как запрашивается сегмент данных - либо он представляет некую область в коде программы (секцию данных), либо же размер для сегмента данных и его размер будут получены из системной кучи, при запуске программы.

Comment: - Для кода `int a = some_val` есть `strong nothrow guarantee`. Это понятно интуитивно, и, думаю, что можно предложить какое-нибудь строгое обоснование *(хотя, наверно, и не слишком тривиальное).*

- Что происходит с `data segment` вообще не должно волновать вас при разработке - имеет смысл оперировать более высокоуровневыми гарантиями и контрактами.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то есть код:

```
func() {
   ...
   int a = 22;
   ...
}
```

В таком случае память для переменной **`a`** будет размещаться в стеке и "выделяться" при входе в процедуру **`func`**.

Я пишу "память выделяется" в кавычках, т.к. при входе в `func` регистр указателя стека просто будет сдвинут (реально уменьшен) на суммарный объем локальных переменных. Т.о. при обращении к **`a`** возможно прерывание по переполнению стека. (Еще вероятнее оно произойдет при вызове первой же функции, если стек в **`func`** переполнится).

Размер выделяемого сегмента данных под стек (он выделяется при порождении процесса) и возможность управления этим размером зависит от ОС и ее настроек. По умолчанию в Windows это 2MB, в Linux около 10MB.

Будет ли средой C++ в таком случае вброшено исключение, откровенно говоря, не знаю.

Если интересно, можете поиграться с программкой

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void
sigh (int s)
{
  write(1,"catch\n",6);
  exit(1);
}

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int sz = av[1]? atoi(av[1]): -1;

  while (sz < 1) {
    printf ("Enter size\n");
    scanf("%d",&sz);
  }

  struct sigaction sa;
  memset (&sa,0,sizeof(sa));
  sa.sa_handler = sigh;
#ifdef ALTST
  sa.sa_flags = SA_ONSTACK;
  stack_t ss;
  ss.ss_sp = malloc(ss.ss_size=1000000);
  ss.ss_flags = 0;
  sigaltstack(&ss,NULL);
#endif  
  sigaction(SIGSEGV,&sa,NULL);

  printf ("Try %d (%x) size\n",sz,sz);
  char a[sz];

  a[0] = 'a';
  printf ("first\n");

  a[sz-1] = 'z';
  printf ("last\n");

  exit (0);
}

avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++  stacksz.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 10400000
Try 10400000 (9eb100) size
first
last
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 10500000
Try 10500000 (a037a0) size
Ошибка сегментирования
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++  -DALTST stacksz.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 10500000
Try 10500000 (a037a0) size
catch
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Идея, надеюсь, понятна. Добавьте ловлю исключений и т.п. крестовые штучки.

**UPDATE**

Если кому-то интересно, то можно добавить код

```
  struct rlimit lim;
  int rc = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK,&lim);
  printf ("get = %d stsize: %ld (soft) %ld (hard)\n", rc,
      (long)lim.rlim_cur,(long)lim.rlim_max);

  int m = av[2]? atoi(av[2]): 1000000;
  lim.rlim_cur += m;
  rc = setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK,&lim);
  if (rc < 0)
    perror("setrlimit");
  rc = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK,&lim);
  printf ("get2 = %d stsize: %ld (soft) %ld (hard)\n", rc,
      (long)lim.rlim_cur,(long)lim.rlim_max);
```

и посмотреть, как это работает.

Comment: Да-да-да. Я лично ловил Segmentation fault с вылетом программы.

Answer (score 3):

О каком динамическом выделении памяти вообще речь? Место для глобальных переменных резервируется заранее, независимо от области их видимости (это, кстати, хорошо знают те, кому слова tiny, small, compact, medium, large и huge ещё о чём-то говорят ;-) Локальне переменные размещаются в стеке, а в случае оптимизации кода могут и стека не требовать.

Answer (score 3):

Если речь идет о С++, то конструкция int a = <некое значение>; выделяет память на стеке. Учите мат. часть. Размер стека есть величина вполне конкретная и зависит от многих факторов: компилятор, операционная система и пр. И в принципе, это значение может быть увеличено. Я сам пользовался порой черной магией и увеличивал размер стека. Это преимущественно нужно было при использовании рекурсии. Для этого использовалась конструкция `#pragma`. Почитать конкретнее можно [тут](http://acm.timus.ru/help.aspx?topic=cpp).